# Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String]'

Tags: swift

When I try to compile this code:

```
func lookupPlayers() {
    print("Looking up \(match?.players.count)")
    
    // Loading ID from players connected in the match
    var idsArray = NSMutableArray()
    if (match != nil) {
        for players in match!.players {
            if let player = players as? GKPlayer {
                idsArray.addObject(player.playerID!)
            }
        }
        
    }
   
    GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle error here
            // if we fail to retrieve player info return and end the match
            print("Error retrieving player info: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.matchStarted = false
            self.delegate?.matchEnded?()
        }
        else {
            // Get info from all players and start the match
            self.playersDict = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: players.count)
            for player1 in players {
                if let player = player1 as? GKPlayer {
                    print("Found player: \(player.alias)")
                    self.playersDict.setObject(player, forKey: player.playerID)
                }
            }
            self.playersDict.setObject(self.localPlayer, forKey: self.localPlayer.playerID)
            
            self.matchStarted = true
            self.delegate?.matchStarted?()
        }
    })
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String]' in this line:
>
> ```
> GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all error tells you that `[AnyObject]` should be a `[String]`. Second of all, why is there `as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject]`. I think the second `as [AnyObject]` is useless. It would be like saying treat this object as a car, which is treated as a car. Doesn't make sense. Have you tried simply replacing `[AnyObject]` with `[String]` and removing the duplicate in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Replace `var idsArray = NSMutableArray()` with `var idsArray = [String]()`. This way you use Swift arrays, not Obj-C `NSArray`s.
2. Then replace:

`GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {`

With:

`GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray as [String], withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {`

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to this issue:
[Problems with code when updating to Swift 2.0. “Cannot convert value..”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932637/problems-with-code-when-updating-to-swift-2-0-cannot-convert-value)

As you know, you need to pass `[String]` fo the first parameter of `loadPlayersForIdentifiers(_:withCompletionHandler:)`. And also `playerId!` definitely is a `String`. Why do you you `NSMutableArray` knowing that?

Change the declaration of `idsArray` as:

```
    var idsArray: [String] = []
```

And the line causing error to:

```
    GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray, withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare idArray as `Array<String>()` instead of `NSMutableArray()`.

Like this:

```
// Loading ID from players connected in the match
    var idsArray = Array<String>()
    if (match != nil) {
        for players in match!.players {
            if let player = players as? GKPlayer {
                idsArray.append(player.playerID!)
            }
        }

    }

    GKPlayer.loadPlayersForIdentifiers(idsArray, withCompletionHandler: { (players, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle error here
         ...
}
    })
```